Problem during 24.04 LTS install. Machine is a dell-xps-13-9350
This is the log-file.
Sep 16 12:23:33 ubuntu subiquity_event.3502[3502]: subiquity/load_cloud_config/extract_autoinstall:
Sep 16 12:23:35 ubuntu subiquity_event.3502[3502]: subiquity/load_cloud_config/extract_autoinstall:
Sep 16 12:23:36 ubuntu subiquity_event.3502[3502]: subiquity/Early/apply_autoinstall_config:
Sep 16 12:23:36 ubuntu subiquity_event.3502[3502]: subiquity/Early/apply_autoinstall_config:
Sep 16 12:23:36 ubuntu subiquity_event.3502[3502]: subiquity/Reporting/apply_autoinstall_config:
Sep 16 12:23:36 ubuntu subiquity_event.3502[3502]: subiquity/Reporting/apply_autoinstall_config:
Sep 16 12:23:36 ubuntu subiquity_event.3502[3502]: subiquity/Error/apply_autoinstall_config:
Sep 16 12:23:36 ubuntu subiquity_event.3502[3502]: subiquity/Error/apply_autoinstall_config:
Sep 16 12:23:36 ubuntu subiquity_event.3502[3502]: subiquity/Userdata/apply_autoinstall_config:
Sep 16 12:23:36 ubuntu subiquity_event.3502[3502]: subiquity/Userdata/apply_autoinstall_config:
Sep 16 12:23:36 ubuntu subiquity_event.3502[3502]: subiquity/Package/apply_autoinstall_config:
Sep 16 12:23:36 ubuntu subiquity_event.3502[3502]: subiquity/Package/apply_autoinstall_config:
Sep 16 12:23:36 ubuntu subiquity_event.3502[3502]: subiquity/Debconf/apply_autoinstall_config:
Sep 16 12:23:36 ubuntu subiquity_event.3502[3502]: subiquity/Debconf/apply_autoinstall_config:
Sep 16 12:23:36 ubuntu subiquity_event.3502[3502]: subiquity/Kernel/apply_autoinstall_config:
Sep 16 12:23:36 ubuntu subiquity_event.3502[3502]: subiquity/Kernel/apply_autoinstall_config:
Sep 16 12:23:36 ubuntu subiquity_event.3502[3502]: subiquity/Zdev/apply_autoinstall_config:
Sep 16 12:23:36 ubuntu subiquity_event.3502[3502]: subiquity/Zdev/apply_autoinstall_config:
Sep 16 12:23:36 ubuntu subiquity_event.3502[3502]: subiquity/Ad/apply_autoinstall_config:
Sep 16 12:23:36 ubuntu subiquity_event.3502[3502]: subiquity/Ad/apply_autoinstall_config:
Sep 16 12:23:36 ubuntu subiquity_event.3502[3502]: subiquity/Late/apply_autoinstall_config:
Sep 16 12:23:36 ubuntu subiquity_event.3502[3502]: subiquity/Late/apply_autoinstall_config:
Sep 16 12:27:22 ubuntu subiquity_event.3502[3502]: subiquity/Ad/has_support_GET:
Sep 16 12:28:51 ubuntu subiquity_event.3502[3502]: subiquity/Ad/has_support_GET:
Sep 16 12:32:56 ubuntu subiquity_event.3502[3502]: configuring apt
Sep 16 12:32:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: start: cmd-apt-config: curtin command apt-config
Sep 16 12:32:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Handling apt to target /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount with config {'debconf_selections': {'subiquity': ''}, 'disable_components': [], 'disable_suites': ['security'], 'preserve_sources_list': False, 'primary': [{'arches': ['default'], 'uri': 'http://ng.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/'}], 'security': [{'arches': ['amd64', 'i386'], 'uri': 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/'}, {'arches': ['s390x', 'arm64', 'armhf', 'powerpc', 'ppc64el', 'riscv64'], 'uri': 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports'}]}
Sep 16 12:32:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Running command ['mount', '--bind', '/dev', '/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/dev'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Sep 16 12:32:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Running command ['mount', '--bind', '/proc', '/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/proc'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Sep 16 12:32:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Running command ['mount', '--bind', '/run', '/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/run'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Sep 16 12:32:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Running command ['mount', '--bind', '/sys', '/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/sys'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Sep 16 12:32:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Running command ['mount', '--bind', '/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/usr/bin/true', '/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/usr/bin/ischroot'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Sep 16 12:32:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Running command ['unshare', '--help'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
Sep 16 12:32:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Checking if target_proc (/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/proc) is a mount
Sep 16 12:32:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: It is, so unshare will use --mount-proc=/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/proc
Sep 16 12:32:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Running command ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--mount-proc=/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/proc', '--', 'chroot', '/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount', 'lsb_release', '--all'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
Sep 16 12:32:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Checking if target_proc (/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/proc) is a mount
Sep 16 12:32:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: It is, so unshare will use --mount-proc=/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/proc
Sep 16 12:32:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Running command ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--mount-proc=/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/proc', '--', 'chroot', '/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount', 'dpkg', '--print-architecture'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
Sep 16 12:32:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: got primary mirror: http://ng.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Sep 16 12:32:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: got security mirror: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Sep 16 12:32:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Apt Mirror info: {'PRIMARY': 'http://ng.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/', 'SECURITY': 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/', 'MIRROR': 'http://ng.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/'}
Sep 16 12:32:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Applying debconf selections
Sep 16 12:32:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Checking if target_proc (/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/proc) is a mount
Sep 16 12:32:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: It is, so unshare will use --mount-proc=/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/proc
Sep 16 12:32:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Running command ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--mount-proc=/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/proc', '--', 'chroot', '/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount', 'debconf-set-selections'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
Sep 16 12:32:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Checking if target_proc (/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/proc) is a mount
Sep 16 12:32:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: It is, so unshare will use --mount-proc=/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/proc
Sep 16 12:32:58 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Running command ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--mount-proc=/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/proc', '--', 'chroot', '/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount', 'dpkg-query', '--list'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: No custom template provided, fall back to modifymirrors in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources on the target system
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Checking if target_proc (/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/proc) is a mount
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: It is, so unshare will use --mount-proc=/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/proc
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Running command ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--mount-proc=/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/proc', '--', 'chroot', '/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount', 'dpkg', '--print-architecture'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Checking if target_proc (/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/proc) is a mount
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: It is, so unshare will use --mount-proc=/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/proc
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Running command ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--mount-proc=/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/proc', '--', 'chroot', '/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount', 'dpkg-query', '--show', '--showformat', '${Version}', 'cloud-init'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Set preserve_sources_list to True in /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/curtin-preserve-sources.cfg with: {'apt': {'preserve_sources_list': True}}
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Checking if target_proc (/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/proc) is a mount
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: It is, so unshare will use --mount-proc=/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/proc
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Running command ['unshare', '--fork', '--pid', '--mount-proc=/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/proc', '--', 'chroot', '/tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount', 'dpkg', '--print-architecture'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_InRelease to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_InRelease
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_main_cnf_Commands-amd64 to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_main_cnf_Commands-amd64
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_main_dep11_icons-48x48.tar.gz to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_main_dep11_icons-48x48.tar.gz
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_main_dep11_icons-64x64%402.tar.gz to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_main_dep11_icons-64x64%402.tar.gz
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_main_i18n_Translation-en to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_main_i18n_Translation-en
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_restricted_cnf_Commands-amd64 to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_restricted_cnf_Commands-amd64
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_restricted_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_restricted_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_restricted_dep11_icons-48x48.tar.gz to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_restricted_dep11_icons-48x48.tar.gz
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_restricted_dep11_icons-64x64%402.tar.gz to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_restricted_dep11_icons-64x64%402.tar.gz
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_restricted_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_restricted_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_restricted_i18n_Translation-en to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-updates_restricted_i18n_Translation-en
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble_InRelease to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble_InRelease
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble_main_binary-amd64_Packages to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble_main_binary-amd64_Packages
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble_main_cnf_Commands-amd64 to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble_main_cnf_Commands-amd64
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble_main_dep11_icons-48x48.tar.gz to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble_main_dep11_icons-48x48.tar.gz
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble_main_dep11_icons-64x64%402.tar.gz to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble_main_dep11_icons-64x64%402.tar.gz
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble_main_i18n_Translation-en to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble_main_i18n_Translation-en
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble_restricted_cnf_Commands-amd64 to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble_restricted_cnf_Commands-amd64
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble_restricted_i18n_Translation-en to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble_restricted_i18n_Translation-en
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-backports_InRelease to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-backports_InRelease
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-backports_main_cnf_Commands-amd64 to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-backports_main_cnf_Commands-amd64
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-backports_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-backports_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-backports_main_dep11_icons-48x48.tar.gz to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-backports_main_dep11_icons-48x48.tar.gz
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-backports_main_dep11_icons-64x64%402.tar.gz to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-backports_main_dep11_icons-64x64%402.tar.gz
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-backports_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-backports_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-backports_multiverse_cnf_Commands-amd64 to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-backports_multiverse_cnf_Commands-amd64
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-backports_multiverse_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-backports_multiverse_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.gz
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-backports_multiverse_dep11_icons-48x48.tar.gz to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-backports_multiverse_dep11_icons-48x48.tar.gz
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-backports_multiverse_dep11_icons-64x64%402.tar.gz to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-backports_multiverse_dep11_icons-64x64%402.tar.gz
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-backports_multiverse_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-backports_multiverse_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-backports_restricted_cnf_Commands-amd64 to /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/ng.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-backports_restricted_cnf_Commands-amd64
Sep 16 12:32:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.3502[5222]: Renaming apt list /tmp/tmp82cvjhg0/mount/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_noble-backports_restricted_dep11_Components-am


There is not a question here. Just a very long error post. Nor did you say what you did to get this log.

Sorry about that, I was trying to install Ubuntu, it kept failing with "We're sorry we're not sure what the error is. You can try restarting your computer and start the installation process again.".
I found a fix, partition related issue https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/s/WM4qtXjA8e


Try Ubuntu in a live session.
Launch GParted partition editor.
In the top right select the disk that you want to install the Ubuntu on.
Delete every partition on this disk (if not possible, right-click and deactivate the partition).
Apply all operations with the green checkmark.
Shutdown the PC.
Boot from the Ubuntu Server installation USB stick and it should work now.

